# Interaction of external light or matter and an Alcubierre warp bubble

Tags: faster-than-light, warp-drives

For a hypothetical vehicle traveling in an [Alcubierre bubble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) at [faster-than-light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light) (FTL) velocities, what would happen when the leading edge of the bubble encounters incident particles or photons?

Let's say either a stationary particle of matter, a photon traveling in the opposite direction to the vehicle, or a photon traveling in the same direction as the vehicle. Would they ultimately end up inside the bubble to encounter the vehicle traveling within?

Answer (score 1):

[This ArXiv pre-print](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5708) by Brendan McMonigal actually answers this problem! He considers particles of velocities ranging from $-c$ to $+c$ (the sign denoting direction relative to the bubble, I believe) and finds that, for the most part, the particles would indeed enter & exit the bubble (receiving a velocity boost) without much trouble.

The trouble, however, is that this particles can damage the shuttle *and* passengers within the bubble!